How can you break a section between multiple pages?
The below section starts in the middle of the page. My problem is that as the number of items increases. The entire section is pushed to the next page which leaves a lot of white space on the page above. Is it possible to ensure that the section content is broken across multiple pages?
% Projects
\section{Project Work}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ @{}l r@{} }
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}[nosep,after=\strut, leftmargin=2em, itemsep=2pt]
      \item \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Project (2024):} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sodales est vel arcu fermentum efficitur.
        \item \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Project (2023):} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sodales est vel arcu fermentum efficitur.
        \item \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Project (2022):} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sodales est vel arcu fermentum efficitur.
                \item \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Project (2021):} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sodales est vel arcu fermentum efficitur.
                    \item \textbf{Lorem Ipsum Project (2020):} Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed sodales est vel arcu fermentum efficitur.
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
\end{tabularx}\\[3pt]


Without a minimal working example that would allow me to test your code immediately, I would guess: remove the minipage and the tabularx environment. Both make not sense and both prevent page breaks inside the itemize environment.

you have a single row single column tabularx (why??) which contains a minipage that contains your list. Neither tabularx nor minipage can break over a page so remove those and just have a list.

Welcome! Do what they^^ said ;).
